# My producer/consumer multithreading program isn't working

Tags: java, multithreading

I've tried hard to do a multithreading java program, but it doesn't work the most times.

In this program there are 4 threads that should read and write values on an ArrayList. In particoular 2 threads (Productors) should write values, and 2 threads (Consumers) should read the values written by the productors. After a consumer read a value, the array should be cleared.

There is a class (Buffer) that should manage the write/read requests.

I'm new in multithreading programming, and I'm not able to let it working properly.
Can someone help me? Here's the code:

Main:

```
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Buffer m = new Buffer();

        Productor p1 = new Productor("Productor 1", m);
        Productor p2 = new Productor("Productor 2", m);

        Consumer c1 = new Consumer("Consumer 1", m);
        Consumer c2 = new Consumer("Consumer 2", m);

        Thread t1 = new Thread(p1);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(p2);
        Thread t3 = new Thread(c1);
        Thread t4 = new Thread(c2);

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();
        t4.start();
    }
}
```

Buffer:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Buffer {
    private ArrayList<Integer> array;
    private boolean state;

    public Buffer() {
        array = new ArrayList<>();
        state = true;
    }

    public synchronized void write(int num) {
        if (!state) {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        }
        array.add(num);
        state = false;
        notifyAll();        
    }

    public synchronized void read() {
        if (state) {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        }
        System.out.println(array);
        array.clear();
        state = true;
        notifyAll();
    }    
}
```

Productor:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Productor implements Runnable {
    private final String NAME;
    private Buffer market;
    private final Random random = new Random();

    public Productor(String NAME, Buffer market) {
        this.NAME = NAME;
        this.market = market;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            int j = random.nextInt(10);
            market.write(j);
        }
    }
}
```

And finally, consumer:

```
public class Consumer implements Runnable {
    private final String NAME;
    private Buffer market;

    public Consumer(String NAME, Buffer market) {
        this.NAME = NAME;
        this.market = market;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            market.read();
        }
    }    
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: For a producer consumer scenario I would prefer a [LinkedBlockingQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html) for storing the jobs.

Comment: Please elaborate on what "I'm not able to let it working properly" means.

Comment: The program often can't end his execution, and still freeze into something like an infinite wait state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic problem is this : Your two consumer threads will read and clear the `Buffer` a total of 4 times, your Producers will write a single value to the `Buffer` a total of 20 times, if they can.

But they cannot.

The consumers most often finish their 4 reads way before the writes are finished, and the writes are then blocked, since `state == false`. So, more often than not the program ends up in a state with one or more producers blocked.

There is another problem though. Both read and write notify on the same object, but if a write thread awakens it cannot be certain it was notified by a read, and as it doesn't check state again, it writes more values into the `Buffer`. For the read, the same is true, it cannot be certain the notify was by a write. **You should always do a wait within a loop that checks the condition, and start waiting again if the condition is not true.**

So the fixes you need are these :

- change the if checks on `state` to while loops
- make sure the consumers do an equal amount of reads.

But, I wonder whether it was really your intention that the producers could not write unless the `Buffer` is empty. If producers are allowed to write even when the `Buffer` has values the fixes are :

- remove the `state` check and wait instruction from the write
- change the if checks on `state` to a while loop in the read
- the reads no longer need to do a notifyAll.

In this scenario the reads are not certain that more writes are coming as a read operation can consume more than one written value, and one or both consumer threads may remain blocked as all writes have been consumed before they do their second loop. To solve this I suggest you look at a 'Poison pill" solution or make sure your reads only consume one value and align the number of reads and writes.

Comment: Thank you! Now the program works and I'm starting to understand multithreading programming better!

Answer (score 0):

There are few basic problems for your producer and consumer program:

(1) Your consumer runs very fast & does n't wait for the producer to place the elements inside the array

(2) The conditions for wait and notify are not proper

You can look at the below updated code which works fine:

**Productor class:**

```
public class Productor implements Runnable {
        private final String NAME;
        private Buffer market;
        private final Random random = new Random();

        public Productor(String NAME, Buffer market) {
            this.NAME = NAME;
            this.market = market;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                int j = random.nextInt(10);
                market.write(j);
            }
            market.setCompleted(true);
        }
    }
```

**Consumer class:**

```
public class Consumer implements Runnable {
        private final String NAME;
        private Buffer market;

        public Consumer(String NAME, Buffer market) {
            this.NAME = NAME;
            this.market = market;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            market.read();
        }    
    }
```

**Buffer class:**

```
public class Buffer {

        private ArrayList<Integer> array;

        public Buffer() {
            array = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        private volatile boolean completed;

        public boolean isCompleted() {
          return completed;
        }

        public void setCompleted(boolean completed) {
         this.completed = completed;
       }

        public synchronized void write(int num) {
            if (array.size() > 0) {
                try {
                    wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
            } else {
                System.out.print(" adding *** ");
                array.add(num);
                notifyAll();     
                System.out.println(num);
            }
        }

        public synchronized void read() {
            while(true) {
                if(isCompleted()) break;
                if (array.size() == 0) {
                    try {
                        wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
                } else {
                    System.out.println(" reading *** "+array);
                    array.clear();
                    notifyAll();
                }
            }
        }    
    }
```

Comment: I've tried your program, but the issue still remain.. execution the most times freezes, take a look https://ibb.co/goeWAa

Comment: you can look at the updated code above, you can set a flag `completed` when the producer is done with all elements

Answer (score 0):

> I've tried hard to do a multithreading java program, but it doesn't work the most times...

Yep, multithreading programs are hard.  Locking and data synchronization between threads is not simple.

Sounds like you have your answer but in the future you should consider using `BlockingQueue<Integer>`.  A blocking queue (such as `LinkedBlockingQueue`) takes care of both the memory sync as well as the signaling between producer and consumers.  They would all share the same queue:

```
final BlockingQueue<Integer> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
Producer p1 = new Productor("Productor 1", queue);
Producer p2 = new Productor("Productor 2", queue);
Consumer c1 = new Consumer("Consumer 1", queue);
Consumer c2 = new Consumer("Consumer 2", queue);
```

With it your producers would do something like:

```
queue.put(num);
```

and your consumers would do:

```
int num = queue.take();
```

You can make the queue bounded by specifying a number to the `LinkedBlockingQueue` constructor.  That way the producers won't fill memory if they run faster than the consumers.

The only trick to them is how to stop the consumers from waiting for items.  Putting a specific value in the queue works.  You can also interrupt the threads once you are done.